# How to import a whole Jupyter NB file in another Jupyter NB?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new on this area and I've stared to learn Python 3 on a Brazilian platform for coding education.

**The thing is:**

I have two programs, one is a "main game" and the other is some "menu selector" for any number of programs I would like to import. The course's teacher is using Pycharm and I'm using Jupyter Notebook to follow the scheddule, so now I'm facing an issue on trying to import and simply nothing happening.

I've searched some forums, Stackoverflow included, and couldn't resolve this.

The main game (adivinhacao.ipynb) is:

```
import random

aleatorio = random.randrange(1,101)
tentativas = 0
rodada = 1
pontos = 1000

print(aleatorio)


# Para selecionar o nível de dificuldade do jogo
print("Escolha o nível de dificuldade")
print("(1) Fácil, (2) Médio, (3) Difícil")

nivel = int(input("Digite o nível: "))

if(nivel == 1):
    tentativas = 10
elif(nivel == 2):
    tentativas = 5
else:
    tentativas = 3

#(more code)
```

And the selector (jogos.ipynb), which is not importing anything, is:

```
!pip install import-ipynb
import import_ipynb
import adivinhacao
```

It worked once (displayed everything I've wrote on adivinhacao.ipynb) and after I've changed one commentary, no more. Can someone help me?

Comment: As far as I know, a Jupyter notebook is not an IDE; they have different purposes and functionality. Any reason you cannot use an IDE like Pycharm or a plain old text editor?

Comment: In fact, I'm using Jupyter NB due the easily installation and importation of dlls targeting web automation projects. Do I need to mandatory do this on Pycharm or another IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
%run adivinhacao.ipynb
```

Comment: It worked! I've tried this method before but something misterious went wrong. Thanks Julio! Now I need to test it as an variable call.

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer